# What windowing events affect MDIGetActive()? The event leading to OnMDIActivate() isn't the only one

Tags: c++, mfc, event-handling

I'm trying to cache the active child window of an MDI application, because profiling has shown that constantly calling MDIGetActive() is a hotspot, and changing the structure to avoid it might be difficult.

I have a child_frame class inheriting from CMDIChildWnd, and my OnMDIActivate() function looks basically like this:

```
afx_msg void child_frame::OnMDIActivate(BOOL bActivate, CWnd* pActivateWnd, CWnd* pDeactivateWnd)
{
   if(bActivate) {
      // Cache the new active child window.
      main_frame *parent = dynamic_cast<main_frame>(this->GetMDIFrame());
      parent->set_cached_active_child(pActivateWnd);
   }
   // Do application-specific activation/deactivation stuff
   // ...
   // ...
   // ...
   // Run the base class event handler
   CMDIChildWnd::OnMDIActivate(bActivate, pActivateWnd, pDeactivateWnd);
}
```

I've tested the cached child against parent->MDIGetActive() at every point within OnMDIActivate() with asserts, and it's always correct at the beginning, middle, end, etc.  I've also tested this at every point in child_frame::OnActivate(), main_frame::OnMDIActivate(), and main_frame::OnActivate(), and the cached result is always correct there too...so it's not necessary or useful to update the cached pointer in those particular handlers.

Unfortunately, the cached result sometimes differs from the real MDIGetActive() result when I go to retrieve it in the actual application code.  This seems to indicate I'm missing some event handler where the active MDI window can change, aside from OnMDIActivate().

**So...exactly what are all the events which can change the active MDI window?**

**EDIT:** At least part of this is looking to be threading-related.  According to [this thread](http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/405d05d1d162fc99.htm), CWnd*'s from MDIGetActive() are not reliable across threads.  In my case, MDIGetActive() is returning a valid CWnd* in the function that spawns workers and a nullptr inside the worker threads, and no obviously related event handler is called.  If this turns out to be the only exception/problem, I'll repost this as an answer.

Comment: I think the framework also calls `MDIActivate` on a child window by default if it's clicked. I think you will struggle to find all the ways this can happen and I can't see why pushing the cache from `child_frame::OnActivate` wouldn't work. Have you tried it, just to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: I've tried, but it isn't necessary or sufficient: It turns out caching the pointer at the beginning of child_frame::OnMDIActivate() alone is enough to make it correct in child_frame::OnActivate(), where I've tested the cached pointer against MDIGetActive() before and after the base class OnActivate() call (the only thing inside it besides the assert tests).  Unfortunately, some other event is causing the real MDIGetActive() value to change at times that aren't triggering OnActivate() or OnMDIActivate() at all...I just still haven't figured out when or why it's happening.

Comment: Understood. However if you dig into the MFC source code for MDI and see just how often and under what conditions the framework calls `MDIActivate`, you'll end up looking for another solution :-( In any case, it's difficult to see why it would be slow - are you confident your profiling has found the culprit?

Comment: It's one of several culprits taking too much time.  On a bottom-up basis in VTune, CMDIFrameWnd::MDIGetActive() is near the top of the list (sometimes second-most expensive) of hotspots.  This is largely because it's called too often structurally, but the calls are spread out and harder to fix.  I'll need to compare to the cost of the cached solution to be sure, but it's responsible for ~8% of program runtime alone, and replacing the complex MDIGetActive() code with a pointer return should be much faster.  For perspective, cutting down *to* 8% of current runtime may be necessary. ;)

Comment: So, it seems one or both of the following is the case:
a.) MDIActivate() does not always trigger OnMDIActivate() or OnActivate() for some reason.
b.) The result of MDIGetActive() can be affected by some function other than MDIActivate().
I'm new to MFC, but you seem to have some source familiarity...so do you know which is the case (or both)?  Whichever is the case, I'm hoping that any change to the value returned by MDIGetActive() will always trigger *some* event handler, and I just need to find the right one.  Is this true, false, or a mystery to both of us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CWnd*'s are not valid across threads, so Windows lies and returns a nullptr when you GetMDIActive() from any thread except the main one.  Since thread changes do not send any WM_ACTIVATE, WM_MDIACTIVATE, etc. messages, they will not trigger OnActivate(), OnMDIActivate(), etc.

There are at least two potential workarounds, but I went with the first, since it's simple and matches my use case:

1. If you're spawning a bunch of worker threads to execute the same function call, and you will never look up the cached active child frame on the main thread until at least after all those threads rejoin, you can cache a nullptr at the beginning of each worker thread and recache the real MDIGetActive() value after they rejoin.  The main thread will continue to pump messages in the meantime, and the cached value will be incorrect during this processing, but it doesn't matter if nothing in the main thread actually uses it.
2. Otherwise, you can find a way to use thread-local storage for the cached child frame and initialize it to a nullptr, and ensure you update only the appropriate thread-local cached value when OnMDIActivate() is called (on the main thread).  This may be tricky depending on your program structure, but it should be more robust and compatible with more threading patterns.

In the end, caching the child frame reduced related code from about 8% of runtime to about 0.02%.